# How can get current id of form in AjaxForm method?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, uploader

```
$('form').ajaxForm
({

beforeSend: function() 
{
// for example i need get current id form here how can ?
// codes
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) 
{
// codes
},
success: function() 
{
// codes
},
complete: function(xhr) 
{
// codes
}


});
```

**I used 2 forms by different id in my page.for example :**

```
<form id="sample1"></form>

<form id="sample2"></form>
```

i need get current form id in **$('form').ajaxForm** .
how can do that ?

Comment: Which method of the ajaxForm object do you want the ID for? I don't know a huge amount about that plugin but the form will either be available through $(this) or somewhere inside one of the params to the function you need the form in.

Comment: [current id of form] i said in my question.but thanks i can slove my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @a.4j4vv1 answer, here's a complete solution:

```
$(function(){

    var currentform; //declare variable here

    $("form[id^='sample']").ajaxForm ({ //"form[id^='sample']" means all forms with id starting with the word 'sample'

        beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm) {
            currentform = jqForm[0]; //retrieve form and assign variable here
        },

        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log("Ajax BeforeSend from "+currentform.id);
        },

        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            console.log("Ajax uploadProgress from "+currentform.id);
        },

        success: function() {
            console.log("Ajax success from "+currentform.id);
        },

        complete: function(xhr) {
            console.log("Ajax complete from "+currentform.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the correct sulotion for get current form id in ajax form plugin is:

```
beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm) {
     // return current form id
     var form = jqForm[0].id;
}
```

Comment: This works, but just to be clearer you should declare `var form` from the outside, and only assign it in the beforeSubmit function, this way the other methods could have access to the value.

Answer (score 0):

i found a way :

i added this event and worked .

```
beforeSerialize: function($form, options) 
        { 
        alert($form.attr('id'));
        return false;// return false to cancel submit  


        }
```

thanks.